# Are the folding.markers hard-coded in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#folding it should be possible to change the markers to something else than "region/endregion".

But following the https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/language-configuration-sample and changing the folding.markers in language-configuration.json seem to have no effect.

I changed the folding.markers in language-configuration.json and tested the extension, but the only markers VS Code is responding to for JavaScript are the default #region/#endregion markers.

Comment: what if you disable the builtin typescript/javascript language support and basic features extensions (that's two extensions. you can find them if you search `@builtin` in the extensions view)?

Comment: I disabled the "JavaScript Language Basics" and "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features". The syntax decorations and all folding disappeared, but the folding.markers still did not make any change.